# Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: "unexpected token ','" how to fix?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I'm new in programming on c# and python

I'm using IronPython library for visual studio

I have this problem: `Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: "unexpected token ','"` , when i run c# code. I want to get "var" of .py func;

My C# code

```
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
        var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/Lib/site-packages/");
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/Lib/");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
        engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:/Users/VYashunin/source/repos/PythonApplication1/PythonApplication1/PythonApplication1.py", scope);
        dynamic min = scope.GetVariable("minValue");

        Console.WriteLine(min);
```

And my .py code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(r"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib")



requestToZabbix = ZabbixAPI(url='http://192.168.1.22/zabbix/', user='admin', password='zabbix')

minValue = None
avgValue = None
maxValue = None

print("Подключение к Zabbix успешно. API Version %s" % requestToZabbix.api_version())

response = requestToZabbix.history.get(itemids=30171, time_from=1530403200, 
                                                      time_till=1532995199, 
                                                      history=0)

vals = [float(x['value']) for x in response]
    minValue = min(vals)
print(minValue)

avgValue = round(sum(vals)/len(vals))
print(avgValue)


maxValue = max(vals)
print(maxValue)
```

What is this and how to fix this problem? Sorry for my eng :)

Comment: Can you post the error with the full stack trace?

Comment: Does exception contain more details, like line where is the unexpected token?

Comment: @Niranjan , Hello! Check my post, pelase :)

Comment: @Reniuz I don't know, how to check more details where is the unexpected token... Can you help me, please?

Comment: [Just debug](http://doc.fireflymigration.com/mastering-visual-studio-debugging.html) and see inner exception for more details

Comment: @Reniuz in line         engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:/Users/VYashunin/source/repos/PythonApplication1/PythonApplication1/PythonApplication1.py", scope);